# In TCL, is it possible to read and edit a file, when file is under continuous write operation

Tags: tcl

Below is the piece of code for how the data is being written into file.

```
set fid [open "file.txt" w]
fconfigure $fid -buffering line
```

The file is under continuous write operation, I would like to know if there is any way to read this file and modify the contents, without closing the fileID i.e., "fid" .

Comment: "and modify the contents" --- is it safe at all?

Answer (score 0):

The `a` (“append”) mode for `open` doesn't let you read, but you can open a separate channel to the same file and then you'll see everything that's actually been written to the file. (With that `-buffering` configuration, that means any partial lines at the end won't be visible.)

Alternatively, you can use the `a+` mode and then you'll be able to `seek` and read content from the file. Writes will still go to the end of the file though (and, for technical reasons, the appending guarantee is relaxed slightly so that it only applies to writes done from Tcl and not to subprocesses that inherit the channel's handle).

The only way to truly modify the file in locations other than the end is to open it separately using an entirely different mode, such as `w+`. You'll obviously want to take a great deal of care with that!